# How do I make threads run sequentially instead of concurrently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

For example I want each thread to not start running until the previous one has completed, is there a flag, something like `thread.isRunning()`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void hello() {
    cout << "thread id: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
}

int main() {

    vector<thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        threads.push_back(thread(hello));


    for (thread& thr : threads)
        thr.join();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the threads are meant to run concurrently, but *what if* I want to control the order?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to control the order? What's your use case?

Comment: If you don't want one thread to run until another has finished then you probably don't want threads. Just write two function calls, one after the other.

Comment: This question, 'how can I make something that is designed from the outset for concurrent operations to run sequentially' is popping up far too often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need the second thread start to run after the first one is completed, is a thread really needed?

For solution I think try to set a global flag, the set the value in the first thread, and when start the second thread, check the flag first should work.

Comment: but then - just to be picky - all threads are still running, they are just waiting for a condition to happen. Nevertheless - they are running (in the sense that they are scheduled in the os scheduler). But there's no other solution.

Comment: If we are making multiple task wait for this one. Why don't just create the threads after finish the first task. Don't put it in a thread.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `thread.isRunning()`. You need some synchronization primitive to do it.
Consider [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) for example.

Answer (score 3):

One approachable way is to use [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async). With the current definition of `std::async` is that the associated state of an operation launched by std::async can cause the returned `std::future`'s destructor to block until the operation is complete. This can limit composability and result in code that appears to run in parallel but in reality runs sequentially.

```
{
    std::async(std::launch::async, []{ hello(); });
    std::async(std::launch::async, []{ hello(); });  // does not run until hello() completes
}
```

Comment: does     std::async(std::launch::async, &Hello_class::hello, &hello_object); is the equivalent for calling a member function?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply control the order like saying "First, thread 1, then thread 2,..." you will need to make use of synchronization (i.e. `std::mutex` and condition-variables `std::condition_variable_any`).
You can create events so as to block one thread until a certain event happend.

See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) for an overview of threading-mechanisms in C++-11.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use semaphore or lock. 
If you initialize semaphore to value 0: 
Call wait after thread.start() and call signal/ release in the end of thread execution function (e.g. run funcition in java, OnExit function etc...)

So the main thread will keep waiting until the thread in loop has completed its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Task-based parallelism can achieve this, but C++ does not currently offer task model as part of it's threading libraries. If you have TBB or PPL you can use their task-based facilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` from C++11. To be able to run threads sequentially array of booleans in used, when thread is done doing some work it writes `true` in specific index of the array. 
For example:

```
mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;
int ids[10] = { false };

void shared_method(int id) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);

    if (id != 0) {
        while (!ids[id - 1]) {
            cv.wait(lock);
        }
    }

    int delay = rand() % 4;
    cout << "Thread " << id << " will finish in " << delay << " seconds." << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(delay));

    ids[id] = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}

void test_condition_variable() {    
    thread threads[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        threads[i] = thread(shared_method, i);
    }

    for (thread &t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread 0 will finish in 3 seconds.
Thread 1 will finish in 1 seconds.
Thread 2 will finish in 1 seconds.
Thread 3 will finish in 2 seconds.
Thread 4 will finish in 2 seconds.
Thread 5 will finish in 0 seconds.
Thread 6 will finish in 0 seconds.
Thread 7 will finish in 2 seconds.
Thread 8 will finish in 3 seconds.
Thread 9 will finish in 1 seconds.
```