# Make pthread wait for another's data

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I am trying to build a program where pthreads wait on a signal from a previous pthread to run, and signal the next pthread when they finish.

For example, say I have 4 pthreads. #1 runs first. I want #2 to wait for #1 to finish before it starts executing and upon its completion, it will signal #3. #3 waits for #2, and eventually signals #4. #4 upon completion simply terminates.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you either want a mutex or a condition variable.

Comment: Suggestion 1 - don't use more then one thread.

Comment: Suggestion 2 - create thread 2 as the last line of thread one, and so on....

Comment: Suggestion 3 - search for all the dups for this illogical functionality.

Comment: @MartinJames If you want to write an answer, write an answer.

Comment: It's an illogical requuirement and there are hundreds of dups of it on SO.  Why would I waste any more time, after all, you didn't spend any time on searching SO before you posted your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make threads run sequentially instead of concurrently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187488/how-do-i-make-threads-run-sequentially-instead-of-concurrently)

Answer (score 3):

For this problem, you don't need a condition variable or a mutex. `pthread_join()` is sufficient.

Pass the thread id of the preceding thread to its successor. Allow the successor to call `pthread_join()`, waiting for its predecessor to finish.

`main()` only needs to `pthread_join()` on the last thread.

However, the functionality is more efficiently achieved in a single thread, as noted in comments.

---

The solution in C might look something like:

```
static void
wait_for_thread(pthread_t *t)
{
    if (t) {
        pthread_join(*t, 0);
        printf("Thread %zu finished...\n", t - threads);
    }
}

static void *
thread_fun(void *arg)
{
    wait_for_thread(arg);
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, thread_fun, i ? &threads[i-1] : 0);
    }
    wait_for_thread(&threads[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

The solution in C++ might look something like:

```
int main ()
{
    std::array<std::thread, 4> threads;
    auto wait_for_thread = [&threads](int p) {
        if (p >= 0) {
            threads[p].join();
            std::cout << "Thread " << p << " finished...\n";
        }
    };
    auto thread_fun = [&wait_for_thread](int p) {
        wait_for_thread(p);
        //...
    };

    for (auto &t : threads) {
        t = std::thread(thread_fun, &t-&threads[0]-1);
    }
    wait_for_thread(3);
}
```